# Python - How to find horizontal distance between two rectangles?

Tags: python

I need to find the horizontal distance between two rectangles (R1,R2) For example, if two rectangles are within one  row, then how can i find the distance between them?

[image]

For Example, if the coordinates of **rectangle 1** are : *x=515, y=942, w=525, h=954*
and coordinates of **rectangle2** are : *x=382, y=938, w=508, h=960*
then how can i find the distance between them in horizontal direction.
Note: I don't need to find the distance from the center of rectangles.

Comment: Please provide more information. How do you get the rect.x and rect.w from the image. How precise is this information? Can you provide input number and the theoretical (correct) result as well the result you obtain?

Comment: Further, if you only want the horizontal distance - why do you use euclidean distance?

Comment: And why from their center? (At least, that is not how I interpret the question.) If you *do* want the center distance, it's as simple as `abs(center1.x - center2.x)`.

Comment: I don't want the distance from center. I just the distance between two rectangles.
I checked this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347085/distance-between-two-rectangles and tried this way but it's of no use..

Comment: This is the simplest arithmetic problem. I believe you can solve it. What is position of right border of the left rectangle?

Comment: ... What's wrong with subtracting the position of one edge from the other?

Comment: @MBo i have added the coordinates in the question

Comment: @AzkaGilani I don't need coordinates. Just hope you can find simple formula

Comment: Your own attempt – which you removed, why? – showed that you determined their center first and use those values. That is why I asked.

Comment: @usr2564301 because i assumed that it was an entirely wrong approach and by mentioning it in this post was causing more confusion for people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance from one vertical edge to another is either from the *right-hand side* of `rect1` to the *left-hand side* of `rect2`, or the other way around. You don't need to know which rectangle is the one on the left or right; you can take the smaller of the two possible values.

```
rect1 = {'x':515, 'y':942, 'w':525, 'h':954}
rect2 = {'x':382, 'y':938, 'w':508, 'h':960}
min(rect1['x']+rect1['w']-rect2['x'],rect2['x']+rect2['w']-rect1['x'])
>>> 375
```

Even though your rectangles overlap, this still is the correct value:

```
382    515     890  1040
 +--------------+
 :              :
 :      +------------+
 :      |       :    |
 :      +------------+
 :              :
 +--------------+
        <- 375 ->
```

Comment: You are a life savior! Thank you so much :)